# CMake file download ignores errors

Tags: cmake

As part of my build, the following lines get executed:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

file(DOWNLOAD <my-url> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/<filename>)
```

At some point the server started acting up, and now (after a long delay) it returns `Internal Server Error (code 500)`. But for some reason, CMake just carries on, like nothing happened and fails later (because the related file was never downloaded). How can I force CMake to stop if the download failed?

OS: CentOS 7

CMake version: 3.14.3

Comment: It seems that CMake treats an operation as **successful**. ([Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download) tells nothing about ignoring the errors, so one could assume the errors are not ignored.) Please, provide exact error messages emitted. Also, you may pass `LOG` option to the `file(DOWNLOAD)` command and print resulted log.

Comment: Note, that using `EXPECTED_HASH` option will protect against broken downloads. But it requires you to know the hash for the file beforehand.

Comment: @Tsyvarev there are no error messages, it is completely silent. I am not a CMake guru by any stretch, but I thought that convention is that failed CMake command causes entire process to stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the status of the [`file(DOWNLOAD ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download) operation by providing the `STATUS` argument:

```
file(DOWNLOAD <my-url> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/<filename>
  STATUS DOWNLOAD_STATUS
)
# Separate the returned status code, and error message.
list(GET DOWNLOAD_STATUS 0 STATUS_CODE)
list(GET DOWNLOAD_STATUS 1 ERROR_MESSAGE)
# Check if download was successful.
if(${STATUS_CODE} EQUAL 0)
  message(STATUS "Download completed successfully!")
else()
  # Exit CMake if the download failed, printing the error message.
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Error occurred during download: ${ERROR_MESSAGE}")
endif()
```

The returned status will be `0` if successful. Otherwise, a different return code and an error message will be provided.

Comment: I thought CMake convention is that if command fails -- entire script fails. What is so special about `file(DOWNLOAD)`? It clearly failed to download the file and yet execution continues...

Comment: @C.M. Actually, in many cases, it is quite the opposite. There are many CMake commands, such as `file(DOWNLOAD ...)`, that may fail in some way and CMake will **not** emit any warning, *nor* terminate execution. The CMake developers are actively pursuing this issue, as it is often cited as one of CMake's big pitfalls. As you can imagine though, it is not a trivial undertaking to support this, as CMake must support so many OS's, compilers, and languages.

Comment: ... seems pretty trivial to me, at least in this particular case.